# Is resisting DC motor bad for it?

Tags: motor, dc-motor

If I keep the shaft of a DC motor in place while it is running does this harm it in any way?  Is it bad for it at all?

Comment: Brushed or brushless?

Comment: A "brushless dc motor" isn't technically a dc motor at all, but rather a dc/ac inverter running an ac motor. If it were a "brushed dc" motor, then holding the shaft static would mean that current was continuously flowing through one set of coils & continuously being opposed by back-torque holding it against moving relative to the surrounding permanent magnets. In this case, damage could likely be avoided/minimal. In a "brushless dc" motor, however, that depends on the actual construction of the internal ac motor & the inverter that's feeding it.

Comment: So would a brushed DC motor get damaged?  What would I have to do to prevent damage if so?

Comment: Many motors have fans. If it has a fan, and the fan is not moving, it will probably overheat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, yes, because the stall current for a motor can greatly exceed the rated current, and exceed the continuous current rating of the motor's windings, brushes and commutator, and burn out the motor.

In some motors it won't instantly kill the motor but heat it - the motor will survive short overloads but can't dissipate the heat from a continuous overload. If you've been making heavy cuts with a saw or a drill it's often good practice to run the motor unloaded for a minute afterwards so the built-in fan blows cool air through it.

This excessive current under heavy load is a necessary consequence of keeping the winding resistance down to keep the motor's efficiency high under normal (high speed) operation.

Cheap motors tend to have incomplete data but for a reasonably complete specification see [this datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1683370.pdf)  and note (the first column)

"Maximum continuous current" 6A. (The nominal rating for 100% duty cycle)
"Starting current" 105A. (This is also the stall current).

Typical motors like the [Mabuchi RS550](http://www.mabuchi-motor.co.jp/cgi-bin/catalog/e_catalog.cgi?CAT_ID=rs_550pcvc) are designed for lower efficiency so the stall current may only be 6-10x the rated current (here 83A vs 10.8A at max efficiency, max continuous current is not specified).

In neither case should you mistake the stall current for the rated current : the RS550 surely cannot survive 83A at 9.6V (about 800W) for very long!

---

However, in your case (a motorized fader) the motor is small, low powered, probably has quite a high winding resistance and low efficiency, and may be able to survive a fairly prolonged stall. This is a deliberate design choice to limit its stall torque rather than injure a sound engineer's fingers! Alternatively its drive current may be deliberately limited. Over and above that, its controller apparently detects its drive current to detect stall or manual override, and cuts off the power before any damage can be done. It is completely safe to stall this motor by hand.

Comment: AFAIK, the stall current is the rated current for motors..

Comment: @m.Alin Generally not the case, though possibly true for very small motors such as this.  See edit...

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably just get a bit warmer.  If it's a low power motor like in a computer fan, then probably no issue at all.  If it's a high-torque device like a traction motor then it may overheat or it may overheat the BLDC driver.

The BLDC driver will probably detect the lack of rotation and give up, and then retry starting a few times.

If it's a sensorless motor+driver, that might cause additional issues because the startup sequence is open-loop and will fail in interesting ways.  Google for "locked rotor" (which is what you are doing to it) and you'll find that different controllers have different ways of dealing with that.

Comment: I was mistaken when I said it was brushless,  What im referring to is a fader on a soundboard,  I assumed it was brushless because its an expensive board but it is brushed.  It is a relatively small servo that stops moving about half a second after it is made to stop.  Do you think that it being unable to move would damage the motor itself?

Comment: In that case it sounds like the servo controller has detected loss of control (i.e. the motor has failed to zero the servo's positional error) and has therefore withdrawn power to the motor to prevent overheating and damage.  I guess it will retry periodically, or it might give up entirely until it's reset.

Comment: Yeah,  It gives up until you nudge it a bit,  then it tries again.

Comment: Sounds like a very high end system. Most likely it will not harm the motor, but resisting the motor will also stress some other mechanical linkage, won't it? It is hard for anyone here to be sure whether what you are doing is OK or not. But based on what you are saying, the motor itself will probably be OK.

Comment: The faders on automated sound boards (mixing consoles) are *designed* to be overridden by holding the knobs. It's all part of how the user interface works. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends...

It depends on the motor and its designed application, how long, any additional cooling.

If the motor was designed for a stall case situation it maybe able to sink the stall current indefinitely.

However... this isn't usually the case and what is typical is tolerance to a stall situation for a finite period of time. I have a 5kW BLAC machine that has a continuous rating of 500W but it does burn out within 30 seconds if it is in stall.